# Does ASP.NET MVC have a Decimal route constraint baked in?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, route-constraint

Does ASP.NET MVC have a decimal route constraint baked into the core library?

I know there's the Regex Constraint but I was wondering if there's any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any, but it would be really easy to write your own.  You just need to implement [`IRouteConstraint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint.aspx), which has a single [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint.match.aspx) method.  [Here](http://nayyeri.net/custom-route-constraint-in-asp-net-mvc) is a blog post that explains it all in great detail.